# Can I delete ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data folder?

Tags: nodeos

I don't want to sync nodeos on my laptop, but want to just connect to an endpoint node. Can I delete the entire folder residing in: ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the folder is tipically composed by two folders, `blocks` and `state`. If you delete both of these folders, you will lose your test blockchain you have run on your local pc. Yes you can delete them if you want to delete your local blockchain...

Comment: I thought it downloads the full EOS blockchain?

Comment: Can I delete the entire eosio folder? I won't be using the test blockchain. Also when you say test blockchain, you mean a testnet version of the blockchain as in not the real one?